# Electron - How to save information?

Tags: electron, saving-data

I've recently learned about Electron, and given I have a rather well amount of knowledge of HTML, CSS, and Javascript, I decided to take a look at it. When I normally make web applications I use MySQL for storing user data mostly through PHP. I noticed Electron doesn't support PHP files like a normal browser does, so I'm curious as to what the best method for saving user data actually is. I read Electron allows for interaction of files like a real application does unlike web apps, but I feel like there's another way. Is there any "standard" when it comes to stuff like this?

Comment: Did you checked about IndexDB or WebSQL?, also i don't see any problem to use a "classic" db, i used postgresq,

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I wouldn't recommend WebSQL as it's been deprecated for a while, and since it uses Chromium as a base with Node.JS, I'm sure IndexDB and/or MongoDB (or any NoSQL storage supported by NodeJS) can do the trick for saving data

Comment: I just put it as an example, i didn't even know that were deprecated

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment, you could use a NoSQL solution (or as Paulo Galdo Sandoval mentioned, the HTML5 storage methods)

I googled and found these resources:
https://medium.com/@ccnokes/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron-3ba6bf66bc1e#.c45jm3tas

https://github.com/jviotti/electron-json-storage